# Source code get entity escaped after migrating

Tags: migration, wordpress.com-hosting, syntax-highlighting

I have a lot of posts with source code on it. After migrating my blog from wordpress.com to self-hosting, the source code all have HTML entity escaping, for example:

```
[code]
  printf(&quot;hello&quot;);
[/code]
```

This causes the rendered source code become `printf(&quot;hello&quot;)` instead of `printf("hello")`

I think this is because the export/import process was using xml file where all non-suitable characters get escaped.

Is there anyway only normal content get escaped, but not `[code]` enclosed content when migrating wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I figured out this isn't related to wordpress migration, but the plugin used to display the source code. Was using Syntaxhighlighter Evolved and it couldn't un-escape HTML entities, changed into Syntax Highlighter for WordPress and all is fine now